# AngularJS ng-repeat which has better performance - reassign values or filter value in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

When using `ng-repeat` which approach has better performance? (assuming there are a large number of users)

**Approach 1: Filter in Controller**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | showBlocked">
  <strong>{{user.id}}</strong>
  <span>{{user.name}}
</div>
```

HTML code in template

```
$scope.users = [
   { id: 1, name: 'alex', isBlocked: true},
   { id: 2, name: 'john', isBlocked: true}
];
```

JavaScript code in Controller

`showBlocked` is a filter which returns a list of blocked users

```
.filter('showBlocked', function() {
  return function(users) {
    return users.filter(user => user.isBlocked);
  }
});
```

**Approach 2: Reassigns users list**

```
<button ng-click="reassignUser(1)">reassign user</button>
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <strong>{{user.id}}</strong>
  <span>{{user.name}}
</div>
```

HTML code in template

```
$scope.reassignUser = function (userId) {
  if (userId === 1) {
    $scope.users = [{id: 1, name: 'alex', isBlocked: true}];
  }
  // in this case just assigns a single user
};
```

[CodePen Demo: ng-repeat filter vs reassign binding](https://codepen.io/sudarsangp/pen/rJQvKP)

Do let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score -1):

`ng-repeat` is evaluated on every $digest cycle, making it extremely slow with two-way data-binding due to $dirty checking. The best solution is to use one-way data-binding with `{{:: data}}` syntax.

But in your example it is indeed better to re-write the array rather than to filter it. The use of **filters** will work **slower**, due to each filter creating a sub collection of the original list. **However**, this can be resolved differently, by hiding the data with `ng-show`. [Here is a post about the complex solution](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2487-filter-vs-nghide-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm), but you can consider this simple example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{name:"John", "id":0}, 
    {name:"Adam", "id":1}, 
    {name:"Ado", "id":2}, 
    {name:"Chris", "id":3}, 
    {name:"Heather", "id":4}, 
    {name:"Stan", "id":5}];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  ID: <input ng-model="query" />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users" ng-show="([user.id] | filter:query).length">
      {{user.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```